# Using Total Commander search to find paths within files

Tags: search, total-commander

Let's say that I have a lot of *.txt, *.php, etc files. Some of these files have filepaths inside of them (links, local filepaths, etc). I've tried using Total Commander's built-in search (Alt+F7) to look for files which contain a specific path (for example, blog/ajax/post-edit.php), but I've found nothing.

I have also tried:

- escaping the forward slashes like so:

  blog\/ajax\/post-edit.php
- enabling RegEx search, and searching for both escaped and original string

How can I find links or filepaths, by using Total Commander's search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex should be able to find anything you need, depending on the structure of the paths you're trying to find.  You shouldn't need to escape a forward slash (though you would with backslashes).

If I wanted to search for any path that started with 'blog' and ended with '.php', I'd probably search use this:

blog[^\s]+?.php

Sorry if that's not valid for Total Commander, but that's the Notepad++ regex pattern, at least.  :)

Comment: Wow, this works! I had no idea I could do this in Notepad++ (used it briefly, then switched to SublimeText, and never really looked back). Thanks! I'm accepting this as an answer which solves my problem (finding filepaths/links), even though the original question was about TC.